# Can Tiff files from ESRI Geodatabase be loaded into QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-database

I have been able to load an ESRI geodatabase which contains shape files into QGIS, however when I try to load a geodatabase containing tiff files I get an error message saying ...."is not a valid or recognized data source". I am assuming it is because it is tiff files? Is there a way to get the tiff files loaded into QGIS through a geodatabase or is there a format I can convert the tiff files to before I put them into the geodatabase? Any suggestion welocme

Nigel

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments to this question: [Use GDAL/Python to add rasters (tiff) to an ESRI File Geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62030/use-gdal-python-to-add-rasters-tiff-to-an-esri-file-geodatabase)
there is no support for rasters in ESRI file geodatabases by GDAL or QGIS.

Furthermore, QGIS does not support File geodatabase by default. See [File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/how-to-get-gdb-esri-file-geodatabase-support-in-quantum-gis-osgeo4w-qgis) for some advice.

The Personal database manpage does not mention raster support either: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pgeo.html

Anyway, you can load tiffs directly into QGIS with `Add Raster`.

Comment: Andre, I am able to get an ESRI geodatabase containing esri shp files into QGIS through osgeo4w ok, it just seems to be the tiff file format I am having difficulty with . I have tried to load the tiff files directly however there are 285 of them (total size ~ 2.1GB) and QGIS will just freeze on me if I try to load them in directly. I thought with the geodatbase it would manage them a bit better?

Comment: Well, ESRI is ESRI and QGIS is QGIS. For a large amount of tiffs, try a virtual raster: http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html. This is incorporated in QGIS under `Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Build Virtual Raster`

Comment: Andre, thanks for help we are trying to migtrate to QIS as the usability in Q is much easier